# Problems using glReadPixels with GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, glreadpixels

I`m trying to render some particles and save the scene to a bmp file,
here is my code

```
// vertex shader

const char *vertexShader = STRINGIFY(
uniform float pointRadius;  // point size in world space
uniform float pointScale;   // scale to calculate size in pixels
void main()
{
// calculate window-space point size
vec3 posEye = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(gl_Vertex.xyz, 1.0));
float dist = length(posEye);
gl_PointSize = pointRadius * (pointScale / dist);

gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(gl_Vertex.xyz, 1.0);

gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}
);

// pixel shader for rendering points as shaded spheres
const char *spherePixelShader = STRINGIFY(
void main()
{
const vec3 lightDir = vec3(0.577, 0.577, 0.577);

// calculate normal from texture coordinates
vec3 N ;
N.xy = gl_TexCoord[0].xy*vec2(2.0, -2.0) + vec2(-1.0, 1.0);
float mag = dot(N.xy, N.xy);

if (mag > 1.0) discard;   // kill pixels outside circle

N.z = sqrt(1.0 - mag);

// calculate lighting
float diffuse = max(0.0, dot(lightDir, N));

gl_FragColor = gl_Color *diffuse;
```

}

Here is the rendering code

Position of the particles are stored in the VBO target_point_buffer as well as corresponding color data

```
void display()
{
//pointsprite
glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE);
glTexEnvi(GL_POINT_SPRITE, GL_COORD_REPLACE, GL_TRUE);
glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE_NV);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//attach shader
glUseProgram(program);
glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(program, "pointScale"), winHeight / tanf(fov*0.5f*(float)M_PI / 180.0f));
glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(program, "pointRadius"),radius[0]*scale);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//use vbo
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

//color buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color_vbo);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
Drawsomething();

}
//Save the scene as an bmp file
void save_as_bmp(char *filename)
{
GLbyte pBits[Imagesize];
GLint iViewPort[4];
GLuint lastBuffer;
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,iViewPort);
glGetIntegerv(GL_READ_BUFFER,&lastBUffer);
glReadPixels(iViewPort[0], iViewPort[1], iViewPort[2], iViewPort[3], GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBits);
writeBMP(filename,pBits);

}
```

I`ve got the expected scene like this:

[image: expect]

However,when I tried to save the scene as a BMP file,the result was not like I expected:

[image: result]

I suppose that it might be something wrong with the gl_TexCoord in the shader, but I can`t figure it out.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

[Set](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` to `1` before your `glReadPixels()` call if you're going to use a three-component `format` like `GL_BGR` with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

Comment: Yes I`ve set GL_PACK_ALIGMENT to 1 but I still got the same problem

Comment: Bmp rows have 4-byte alignment. For this you should use value of 8 (that's weird, but that's a specification statement)